# Why in PHP printf() "g" type-specifier gives wrong value?

Tags: php, printf

As per [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sprintf.php),
"g - shorter of %e and %f"

I have executed this statement:

```
printf("e:%1\$.3e\nf:%1\$.3f\ng:%1\$.3g", .123e2);
```

And this is output:

```
e:1.230e+1 // long value
f:12.300 // shorter value
g:12.3 // here g gives something else
```

Why `"g"` gives something else, am I getting the docs wrong?

```
$ php -v
PHP 7.1.10 (cli) (built: Oct 19 2017 15:16:13) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.5.1, Copyright (c) 2002-2017, by Derick Rethans
```

Comment: This issue isn't unique to PHP, although PHP is the only language I know where the *official documentation* makes this error. The same misdocumentation of the `g` specifier can be found in relation to many languages, including C - and the real behaviour is the same in all of them. See my writeup at [What precisely does the %g printf specifier mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162152/what-precisely-does-the-g-printf-specifier-mean), which quotes the same PHP docs that you quote here, and in which I explain how the real behaviour differs from just picking the shorter of `%f` and `%e`.

Answer (score 0):

`sprintf()` eventually delegates to the `sprintf(3)` C function. From the `printf(3)` man page:

> ```
> Precision
>
>    [...] This gives ... the maximum number of significant digits for g and G 
>    conversions...
> ```

Therefore the PHP documentation is, at best, inaccurate.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. So it internally cuts off insignificant zeros.

Comment: Not quite. `$ printf '%.5g\n' 123.001`
`123`
`$ printf '%.5g\n' 123.1234`
`123.12`