# Matrix of structure C

Tags: c, arrays, matrix, struct

So I have this code where I'm trying to define a dynamic matrix with n*n size.
It turns out that, instead of the output printing the value for G, it prints 0 instead. Any idea why?

```
#define G 6.67408e-11

typedef struct matrix
{
    double mass;
    double cmx;
    double cmy;

}MATRIX;

MATRIX **mtr;

void main(int argc, char** argv){
    const long n = atoi(argv[1]);

    mtr = (MATRIX**)calloc(n,sizeof(MATRIX*));
    for (int i=0; i<n; ++i)
    {
        mtr[i]=(MATRIX*)calloc(n,sizeof(MATRIX));
    }
    mtr[0][0].cmx=G;
    printf("%f\n", mtr[0][0].cmx);
}
```

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. A [mcve] would be `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { printf("%f\n", 6.67408e-11); }`

Comment: Solution: use `%g`.

Comment: In a quick glance, it is probable that 6.67408e-11 is a really small value and it gets rounded to 0.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162152/what-precisely-does-the-g-printf-specifier-mean

Comment: Also it doesn't print `0`, it prints `0.000000` or similar.

Answer (score 2):

Just use `%e` or `%g` to display the output. If you use `%f`, you're telling the compiler to print the number in standard format, that would be `0.0000000000667408` but since %f is formatted as default with 6 decimal ciphers the compiler rounds it to `0.000000` .

Comment: "%.16f\n" would be another way if OP has severe allergies to scientific notation.